# Position of "prochain"?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

Why is it "l'année prochaine" but "la prochaine fois"? Going down [this list](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/next) of expressions using the word, I can discern no pattern for when it goes before the noun and when it goes after.

I am familiar with the standard adjectival rules of position, but there seems to be no difference in meaning here.

What is the logic?